# Just trying to install Git on a new Kubuntu instance, getting "please insert Kubuntu 19.10 into cdrom"

Tags: kubuntu, git

I run install git and get the following error:

> Please insert 'Kubuntu 19.10 *Eoan Ermine* - Release amd64 (20191017)'
>   in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]

I cannot do anything after this, it just locks up and I have to exit.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment all CDrom entries (usually on the very beginning of the file).

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add # before each line you wish to comment. Then simply run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Comment: You should use `sudo -H gedit` unless you wish to create a login loop.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!